# How can I extract the unique variables in one column conditional to a variable in another and make a new data frame with the output?

Tags: r

I would like to extract the number of camera trap nights (CTN) (one column in df) per camera trap station (another column in DF) so I can work out relative abundance indices for each cameras station. For example Station 1 has had 5 triggers/events (of the same species) and has had 30 CTN. It is listed in my database 5 times (has 5 rows). I want to extract the unique CTN for Station 1 and subsequently all the other Stations in the DF.

Data frame:

```
EventID  CameraStation  CTN   
001      Station 1      30  
002      Station 1      30  
003      Station 1      30  
004      Station 1      30  
005      Station 2      29  
006      Station 2      29  
007      Station 2      29  
008      Station 2      29  
009      Station 2      29  
010      Station 3      31  
011      Station 3      31
```

I have tried to use 'unique' and 'with' but do not get the result I want.

```
with(unique(rai.PS[c("CameraStation", "CTN")]), table(CameraStation))
```

I expect to get the following results;

```
CameraStation    CTN

Station 1        30
Station 2        29
Station 3        31
```

I.e. Station 1 is only listed once with the outcome of CTN and in a new data frame.

But instead I get;

```
CameraStation
Station 1
1
Station 2
1
Station 3
1
```

I am assuming it is giving me the unique station once without the CTN as the criteria.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example so that it is easier for others to help you.

Comment: I would like to know the value of CTN (one column in df) for each 'unique' CameraStation (another column in df). CameraStation has more than 1 entry so is listed several times in the same column but always has the same associated CTN. I used the following code; with(unique(my.df[c("CameraStation", "CTN")]), table(CameraStation)) but it didn't give me what I wanted.

Comment: Ronak Shah - I hope this helps for being more reproducible. Regards, Adam

Comment: You're overthinking by adding `table`. Delete that part of your code, `unique(rai.PS[c("CameraStation", "CTN")])` should be fine.

Comment: It works great, thank you! You are right, it was that simple.